# Cocoapod - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

While validating created pod I got these error.

Anshul-MAC238:ASExtendedCircularMenu MAC238$ **pod lib lint**

-> ASExtendedCircularMenu (0.1.0)

> ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can 
>   use `--verbose` for more information. NOTE  | xcodebuild:  clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have successfull pod install then you just use clean-> Build -> Run.

if not work just delete derived data from Xcode Prefence then restart Xcode.